# WordPress Login with REST API?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, authentication

Guys I am trying to create an endpoint with REST API that will log the user that goes to the endpoint. Any ideas on how to do it correctly? Here is what I've got so far :

```
function mm_login_user( $request = null ) {
    $response = array();
    $parameters = $request->get_json_params();

    isset( $parameters[ 'user_login' ] ) ? $user_login = sanitize_text_field( $parameters[ 'user_login' ] ) : $user_login = '';
    isset( $parameters[ 'user_password' ] ) ? $user_password = sanitize_text_field( $parameters[ 'user_password' ] ) : $user_password = '';

    $error = new WP_Error();

    if ( empty( $user_login ) ) {
        $error->add( 400, __( "user_login field is required.", 'mm' ), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
        return $error;
    }

    if ( empty( $user_password ) ) {
        $error->add( 400, __( "user_password field is required.", 'mm' ), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
        return $error;
    }

    $creds = array(
        'user_login'    => $user_login,
        'user_password' => $user_password,
        'remember'      => true
    );

    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        $error->add( 400, __( "Invalid Username or Password.", 'mm' ), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
        return $error;
    }

    wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );
    $auth_cookie = wp_generate_auth_cookie( $user->ID, mm_keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year(), 'auth' );
    $auth_cookie_logged_in = wp_generate_auth_cookie( $user->ID, mm_keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year(), 'logged_in' );
    $response[ 'auth_cookie' ] = $auth_cookie;
    $response[ 'auth_cookie_logged_in' ] = $auth_cookie_logged_in;
    $response[ 'wp_nonce' ] = wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' );
    $response[ 'code' ] = 200;
    $response[ 'message' ] = __( "User Logged In.", "mm" );
    set_transient( 'user_id', $user->ID );

    return new WP_REST_Response( $response, 200 );
}
```

The problem here is that if I try to log the user here with :

```
wp_set_current_user( $transient, $user->user_login );
wp_set_auth_cookie( $transient, true );
```

The servers throw 502. That's why I've set a transient that I later use to log the user on "template_redirect" but the issue here is when the user is logged and someone else uses the endpoint it kicks the current user and now everyone is logged as the last user that has used the endpoint. Please help I am stuck :((

Comment: Maybe try [Basic-Auth](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth), or use it as a starting point, another solution based on tokens and QR codes is [qr-user-login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qr-user-login/)

Comment: QR Codes?? Huh?

Comment: I also login for rest api for mobile phone to expose API like login.registration,lost password,edit profile. if there is any solution . please post here. it will be the great help for me.

Comment: The solution is quite long and all I can do is post a link here - https://github.com/YuxelOsmanow/wp-login-user-via-api